# Scaling objects from a center point by a specific number

Tags: c++, math, vector, geometry, scaling

I'm not sure if doing something wrong in my program or not but I could use some quick guidance if you could and more than likely the problem is I'm thinking to hard about it (which is always the case for me) and I can't think of the way to explain it (hence the crappy title of this question) and gave me a little trouble simply Googling for help.

I'm aware of how to scale an object by way of:

```
double scale = 2.0;
Array<Real2> newPoints;
Foreach(Real2 point, points)
{
Vector2 vector = point - centerPoint;
vector *= scale;
newPoints.Add(center + vector);
}
```

**However let's say I wanted to scale the size of the object by 3.6(units) instead of by a percentage.. How would I go about that?**

It made sense to me at least that I would do something along the lines of

```
vector *= 1 - (3.6/vector.length);
```

but I'm still getting incorrect results running my application. Any help on this issue? Like I said sorry if I explained this incorrectly, I'm horrible when it comes to that stuff so if there's anyway i can clarify let me know. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're wanting to do. Say you started with the vector (0, 10). What would you want the end result to be? (0, 13.6)? (0, 3.6)? (0, 6.4)?

Comment: What do you mean by "scale the size by 3.6"? By definition, scaling means multiplying by a constant factor, as the first example does. It sounds like you want to do something else, but it's not clear what.

Comment: Sorry, okay let's take for example, I have a picture, and I want to scale the picture by 3.6 pixels from each vertices @MikeSeymour does that make sense?

Comment: @TaylorBrandstetter ^^ Does that make sense?

Comment: @Chris: OK. In that case, the scale would be `(old_size + 3.6) / old_size`. It would still be the same for all the vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to scale the object so that it's new size is (say) 3.6 units larger than it's old size. In that case, the code would be the same except for

```
scale = (old_size + 3.6) / old_size;
```

You still need to scale each vector by the same amount, in order to preserve the overall shape of the object.

Comment: By `old_size` you mean `length` of a vector? Because, it seems to me, in this case the scale then will be different for each vector...

Comment: @PetrBudnik: The size of "the object" that wants to be 3.6 units larger.

Comment: I was just about to ask the same question? I can kind of see where you went with this and I'm starting to un-cloud here a little bit lol because I understand where you came from.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I see what you mean. What is confusing that 2D vectors usually describe 2D objects. I guess, "increasing size of a square by 3.6 units" does not make much sense to me. There should be a direction specified along which this happens. I suppose though, the OP meant "increasing in all directions by the same number of units". Of course, this does not preserve the overall shape in general.